# How to redirect that page which i enter in inputbox in pagination in datatable?

Tags: jquery, datatables

This is not working properly.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable( {
            "pagingType": "full_numbers"
        } );
    } );
```

I'm trying to make pagination with input box when input any page number in input box then redirect on that page. How to make that in data table. Please give any example.

Comment: Some context would be helpful. Could you post your HTML code?

Comment: i have no HTML code for that but I'm trying to make it.

Comment: Refer this --> http://datatables.net/reference/api/page%28%29 <----